# Permission denied although I can do whoami

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

My local machine is running Windows and I am trying to connect to a Bitbucket server using Git Bash and SSH.

If I run `whoami` on the remote repository:

```
ssh -p 7999 -i /c/Users/my-username/.ssh/id_rsa git@my-repo.com whoami
```

I get a correct reply:

```
my-username
```

However, if I try to ping the repository:

```
ssh -T git@my-repo.com
```

I am asked for my password 3 times and then my access is rejected.

```
This is a private computer system with access restricted to
those with proper authorization.  If you are not specifically
authorized to access data on this system, disconnect now.
All information and communications on this system are
subject to review, monitoring, and recording at any time
without notice or permission.  Unauthorized use or access
may be subject to prosecution or disciplinary action.


Password:
Password:
Password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).
```

Any idea why my access is rejected?

**EDIT**

I also tried

```
ssh -p 7999 -T -i /c/Users/my-username/.ssh/id_rsa git@my-repo.com
```

and the result is the same

Comment: So you probably are not allowed for interactive shell or interactive shell is not defined. What happens with `ssh -p 7999 -i /c/Users/my-username/.ssh/id_rsa git@my-repo.com ls`? You can try `bash` instead of `ls` for interaction as well.

Comment: You're logging in with username `git`, but `whoami` says `my-username`?

Comment: @robertklep yes

Comment: @octavian that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @robertklep Yes, it does because I'm passing a key `/c/Users/my-username/.ssh/id_rsa` which is generated for `my-username`

Comment: @RuDevel `Bitbucket cannot execute "ls". The command is not supported as entered. Ensure you are using a supported SCM, check the syntax and try again.`

Comment: @octavian I guess it's some BitBucket weirdness, that they somehow correlate the key with the BB username (which isn't how SSH normally works). Which would also probably account for not being able to log in properly (BB only uses SSH as a transport mechanism to their Git repo's and not to full shell accounts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [this document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/enabling-ssh-access-to-git-repositories-in-bitbucket-server-776640358.html) explains why you can't log in:

> To prevent security issues, the embedded SSH server has been locked down to allow execution of a small set of commands for Git hosting. The only commands that are supported are `git upload-pack`, `git receive-pack`, `git archive-pack` and `whoami` (a custom `whoami` implemented in Bitbucket Server not the `whoami` command that exists on Linux). It is not possible to open an SSH shell using the embedded server to execute arbitrary commands on the server.

Although this relates to a product called "BitBucket Server", I assume that it also applies to the cloud-hosted version of BitBucket.

Comment: I am using Bitbucket server actually.

Comment: So that means I can't do `git push` or `git pull` either?

Comment: @octavian those commands are ultimately implemented with the various `*-pack` commands, so they should work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss the private key on the second command. Thus SSH falls back to username/password.

Try

```
ssh -p 7999 -T -i /c/Users/my-username/.ssh/id_rsa git@my-repo.com
```

Comment: I have tried that one as well, with the same result. I updated my question.

Comment: However- without the private key `-i ...id_rsa` and the port `-p 7999` you will most probably get nowhere. If you happen to have username and password and username is different to `git` try using that username e.g. `octavian@my-repo.com`. What you call is btw. not exactly a ping but an interactive login.